# Working with newly added table records in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-performance, records

I am new to Mysql. Is there any way available to work with newly added records only? 
My table contains more than 1 million records. Every 5 mins, there is a new record is added. To find the `avg()` of the table, it takes minimum 3.5 sec. Whenever I find the `avg(),` the entire row is calculated. Instead of that, I want to calculate `avg()` for the newly added records only. It reduces the time of execution. How do I find the last position from which I should calculate?

Example:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
| Id    | name | data   |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 01    | aaa  | 10045  |
   .      .      .     
   .      .      .      
|1000000| xxx  | 10012  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

avg of 1000 records=500;---> takes 3sec

avg of 1100 records=600;---> takes 3.5sec

Comment: Do you have any auto-incrementing field or Timestamp/date added/updated?

Answer (score 0):

@KAJ's comment and @Arif's answer and pointing you in the right direction. But consider making a view for this as well...it's essentially a 'query you need to run all the time', and those sorts of queries make the best candidates for a view.

See @Arif's answer for a good starting point to make a `VIEW_recent_additions`.

Comment: It's for the sake of organization, yes. Performance? Not so much.